# Restricted usage of repeat-measure sign

Tags: notation, engraving, repeats

I just found this [pdf](https://learnmusictheory.net/PDFs/pdffiles/01-01-08-RepeatSigns.pdf) which says:

> The repeated measure/bar is used only for drums, piano, or guitar.

Is this still the case? And if so, why isn't it used for other instruments, e.g. violin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very often, the parts for non 'rhythm section' instruments (keys, bass, guitar, drums) are not inclined to be quite as repetitive as chords or drum patterns. Often the repeated measure is simply not needed in other instruments. However, it can definitely be found in parts for other instruments from time to time, and any reasonable player of any instrument would understand its meaning.

Comment: I think what they really wanted to say was that the measure repeat symbol is much more common in pop, rock, and jazz and quite rare in classical music, at least from my experience.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Measure repeats are very common in classical orchestral parts for all instuments.

Comment: @PiedPiper I have yet to see any, but what I’ve read is mostly older and not necessarily editions for modern performance